# How to access private fields from parent class in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, private

I have a Heap class that has a private `values` field. This is good since I do not want anyone to be able to directly modify `values`.

```
class Heap {
  
  #values;
  
  constructor(array = []) {
    this.#values = array;
  }

    insert(item) {
    this.#values.push(item);
    this.#bubbleUp(this.#values.length - 1);
  }
}
```

But now I would like to extend my Heap class into a PriorityQueue subclass. In this class I need to change the signature of some of the methods (for example `insert`) so that it assigns a priority to a value. However, I cannot figure out how to access the `values` field from the base class. For instance, given the following PriorityQueue class:

```
class PriorityQueue extends Heap {
  
  constructor(array = []) {
    super(array);
  }
  
  insert(item, priority) {

    // Error: Private field '#values' must be declared in an enclosing class
    this.#values.push({ item, priority }); 
    this.#bubbleUp(this.#values.length - 1);
  }
}
```

I get an error when trying to push a value onto `values`.

Is there any way around this problem? I want to make a field private in the base class, but still accessible to the subclass.

Thanks!

Comment: Just call the parent's `insert` method? `super.insert({ item, priority })`.

Comment: "*I want to make a field private in the base class, but still accessible to the subclass.*" that is what protected access is. However, JS doesn't have that for now. So you whatever you want to use in subclasses has to be public.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I cannot figure out how to access the `values` field from the base class.

This is not possible. Private really means private in JS. Don't use it if you want the field to be accessible outside of the class.

> I want to make a field private in the base class, but still accessible to the subclass.

That would be a protected member, which JS doesn't support.

> Is there any way around this problem?

Well, you don't actually need to access the `.#values`. All you need to do is call the base class `insert` method:

```
class PriorityQueue extends Heap { 
  insert(item, priority) {
    super.insert({ item, priority });
  }
}
```

> I would like to extend my `Heap` class into a `PriorityQueue` subclass. In this class I need to change the signature of some of the methods (for example insert) so that it assigns a priority to a value.

This is a bad idea. A subclass should not change the method signatures, otherwise it will violate the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Instead, use [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), where a priority queue *has* or *contains* a heap:

```
class PriorityQueue {
  #heap = new Heap(v => v.priority); // assuming it takes a custom comparator?
  
  push(item, priority) {
    this.#heap.insert({ item, priority });
  }
  pop() {
    return this.#heap.…
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, your post helps a lot. My `Heap` class does use a comparator. I never even considered structuring the PriorityQueue to have a heap instance rather than inheriting from the Heap class. I clearly have much to learn.

On a side note, do you recommend any books to learn topics such as *composition over inheritance*?